# how to record pyvirtualdisplay session

Tags: python, selenium, xvfb

I have a web scraper using Selenium in Python 3, I need to record a video of the session in order to do some debugging. I first create Xvfb virtual display:

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
display = Display(visible=0, size=(1000, 1000))  
display.start()
```

then I create chromium session:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get("myURL.com")
#
#some web scraping happening here....
#
driver.quit()
display.sendstop()
import sys
sys.exit()
```

My problem is, it sometimes doesn't stop the `driver` and `display`, I want to record a video in order to see what's happenin. Any ideas on how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new display (you already do that)
2. Start video recording.
3. Start browser via webdriver.
4. Wait until browser completed you scenario.
5. Stop video recording.
6. Destroy display.

Comment: `2. Start video recording.` How do I do that? Is that some function attached to the pyvirtualdisplay?

Comment: Set display number (where your browser is running) when you starting video recorder, like `export DISPLAY=:123   ./run-my-video-recorder`.